# Implementing instant messaging in my android application

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, onesignal

everyone I know discussion questions aren't welcomes here, so I'm trying to make this as programmatic as possible. In a nutshell I'm asking for better ways to do this, or ways to optimize my existing code. My application was created through the use of the `Unity3D` game engine, however it's not a game. I just find the engine really easy to use, because of this I am using a service website called [OneSignal](http://onesignal.com). Enough of the rambling, any more and it becomes irrelevant to the question.

This is my first attempt creating an instant messaging application that does not make use of `Sockets`. So my over-all design is sloppy at best. However, here's my setup:

Currently I'm making use of the HTTProtocol in which I store all of my logic on my webserver using PHP. Basically what I'm doing is returning database results in a `JSON` format to be parsed in C# using `SimpleJSON` and then handled by the application to show new messages, etc. (Based on the "has read" state in the application / on the server.)

Here's where it becomes problematic in my eyes. While I can send a push notification to the user when the receive a new message, how would I pull all of these messages from the server? The only logical way that I've thought of to do this was to constantly poll the web-server every 5-10 seconds and check to see if there's any new messages. If there are, then add them to the appropriate message list and apply the "unread message" attribute.

So should the phone store all of the users previous messages in memory? or should I pull all of the messages from the database each time? The second option seems like it would cost much more bandwidth than required for a simple chat feature. However it seems like a bunch of messages stored on a device would cause device clutter, and reading from the flat-file storage containing the messages every time you opened the message would (In my opinion) use quite a bit of disk I/O. So should the messages be stored in memory? Then you run into the device constantly running low on memory, as androids use quite a bit and it'd never be collected by the GC unless the message (thread) was deleted.

I was told by a friend that I should just deliver the messages through push notifications and handle them on the device as they're received, but an issue with that is that push notifications aren't always received and then we'd end up with a lot of lost messages.

If we poll the database constantly then we'd be draining the users battery.

I'm at a complete loss for what to do here, and would like some guidance. This is my first android application and while it's coming along very, very nicely, the feature I put off to the end because I figured it would be simple (Messaging) has turned out to be the most difficult.

If this is the incorrect place to ask a question like this, could you please (Accompanied by your immediate down-vote) post in the comments where this belongs.

Comment: Using OneSignal to send push notifications when the user is not in your app will be the most efficient for network traffic and the device's battery life. This is because GCM is used on Android devices and APNS on iOS which is handled on the OS level for both platforms. For an instant message app you might want to look into Adnan's answer when users are in your app.

Comment: @jkasten - Push notifications are also handled while the user is in the application, just not displayed as a 'notification'. The problem with push notifications is that you can't rely on them to transfer data, as they're not always delivered.

Comment: I am suggesting you use both Push Notifications and your own in-app messaging implementation. Use Push Notifications when the recipient of the IM isn't in your app or they didn't receive a message they should of. When both users are active in your app chatting back and forth you should use your own in-app messaging so responses are instant. The logic should be handled on your own server of when to send a push notification, only create a notification if the recipient could not get a message with your own IM implementation.

Comment: I recommend using push notifications in this way as you don't want to keep waking the device on an interval (even every 15 minutes) to check for messages in the background as it will not be battery efficient for the device. Push Notifications are quite reliable but of course are not ideal for very frequent responses back and forth so only use them as a back up when the user isn't in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and implement a XMPP client in your application, since Unity3d suports .net/mono, you should be able to find a [suitable library](https://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Push notifications aren't really meant for IM (at least not for every single message)